# Is releasing an iOS application ipa without UDID (jailbreaked iPhones only) (of an app not yet in the app store) a good idea?

Tags: android, ios, app-store, apk, ipa

In other words: can someone use that ipa file to upload it to the appstore?
And what about an android apk file?

Comment: I don't think someone could upload your iPhone app directly to the app store.  In order for the upload to be accepted the binary needs to be signed with one of the developer keys that you've associated with your app's bundle identifier.  Someone without the proper key/certificate would not be able to do this.  Not sure with respect to Android, however.

Answer (score 2):

With an android apk someone could sign it themselves and then release it to the market (the android version of the app store). This is actually how a lot of android malware is published.